# VBA Codes clash with one another

Tags: excel, vba

Can you please advise how I can fix the following codes so that they do not class with each anymore. I apologise that I had to put down a lot of codes here but I really have no idea which of those are making them clash with each other.

So, I have this part to return "Rollup" for any empty Sales and Production cells if "Shipped" in Column AU (47th column).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim counter As Long
Dim lastcolumn As Long

lastColumn = Me.Cells(1, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Shipped without Title Transfer
      If Me.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value = "MB51 Shipped" Then
        For counter = 1 To lastColumn
          If (Me.Cells(1, counter).Value = "Sales" Or Me.Cells(1, counter).Value = "Production") _
          And IsEmpty(Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value) Then
            Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value = "Rollup"
          End If
        Next counter
      End If
```

Then I have this piece to return "x" in column AX (50th column) if the last Sales column has "Title Transfer".

```
Dim r As Range, r1 As Range, counter As Long
Dim MaxCol As Variant, rg As Range, j As Long

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:AP")) Is Nothing And Target.Column Mod 4 = 2 Then
    Set r = Intersect(Target, Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion, Columns(Target.Column).Resize(, 3))
    Call DoCells(r)
  End If

'Automatically put "x" if Title Transfer in any Sales columns
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:AP")) Is Nothing And Target.Column Mod 4 = 2 Then
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set rg = Range("N" & Target.Row & ":AP" & Target.Row)
    MaxCol = 0
    For j = Columns("AP").Column To Columns("N").Column Step -4
      If Cells(Target.Row, j) <> "" Then
        If j > MaxCol Then MaxCol = j
      End If
    Next
    If MaxCol Mod 4 = 2 Then
      If Cells(Target.Row, MaxCol).Value = "Title Transfer" Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 50).Value = "x"
      Else
        Cells(Target.Row, 50).Value = ""
      End If
    End If
  End If

'This I have 8 Sales Column, however, I only put 1 line down for demonstration
Set r = Intersect(Target, Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion, Columns(colSales1).Resize(, 3))
    If Not r Is Nothing Then Call DoCells(r)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:AP")) Is Nothing And Target.Column Mod 4 = 2 Then
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set rg = Range("N" & Target.Row & ":AP" & Target.Row)
    MaxCol = Evaluate("=MAX(IF(" & rg.Address & "<>"""",COLUMN(" & rg.Address & ")))")
    If MaxCol Mod 4 = 2 Then
      If Cells(Target.Row, MaxCol).Value = "Title Transfer" Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 50).Value = "x"
      Else
        Cells(Target.Row, 50).Value = ""
      End If
    End If
  End If

End Sub
```

Here is the DoCells sub that one of the lines calls up.

```
Private Sub DoCells(r As Range)
    Dim r1 As Range
    For Each r1 In r.Cells
        With r1
            Select Case .Column
                Case colSales1, colSales2, colSales3, colSales4, colSales5, colSales6, colSales7, colSales8
                    Call MasterChange(.Resize(1, 3))
                Case colProduction1, colProduction2, colProduction3, colProduction4, colProduction5, colProduction6, colProduction7, colProduction8
                    Call MasterChange(.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3))
                Case colDay1, colDay2, colDay3, colDay4, colDay5, colDay6, colDay7, colDay8
                    Call MasterChange(.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 3))
            End Select
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is my data structure using Markdown Table:

```html
| Title  | Engine Family | Market Segment | Customer | Engine Model | S/N | Build Spec | ACTL.FINISH | Sales Order | Item | Committed Date | EPS Date   | Target | Sales | Production | Day 1 | Status | Sales          | Production | Day 2          | Status | Sales   | Production | Day 3   | Status           | Sales   | Production | Day 4   | Status           | Sales   | Production | Day 5   | Status           | Sales   | Production | Day 6   | Status           | Sales   | Production | Day 7   | Status           | Sales   | Production | Day 8   | Status           | Comments | MB51 Shipped | FPS? | Plant | Title Transfer |
|--------|---------------|----------------|----------|--------------|-----|------------|-------------|-------------|------|----------------|------------|--------|-------|------------|-------|--------|----------------|------------|----------------|--------|---------|------------|---------|------------------|---------|------------|---------|------------------|---------|------------|---------|------------------|---------|------------|---------|------------------|---------|------------|---------|------------------|---------|------------|---------|------------------|----------|--------------|------|-------|----------------|
| Rollup | PS            | APU            | ABC      | 46C12        | 1   | BS1        | 0000-00-00  | 101         | 450  | 2019-12-31     | 2019-12-31 | Rollup | Green | Rollup     | Green | Sales  | Title Transfer | Yellow     | Title Transfer | Sales  |         |            |         | Sales/Production |         |            |         | Sales/Production |         |            |         | Sales/Production |         |            |         | Sales/Production |         |            |         | Sales/Production |         |            |         | Sales/Production |          |              |      |       | x              |
| Yellow | PS            | FEP            | ADG      | PS3          | 3   | BS3        | 0000-00-00  | 103         | 180  | 2019-12-16     | 2019-12-20 | Yellow | Green | Rollup     | Green | Sales  | Title Transfer | Yellow     | Title Transfer | Sales  | Rollup  | Rollup     | Rollup  | Sales/Production | Rollup  | Rollup     | Rollup  | Sales/Production | Rollup  | Rollup     | Rollup  | Sales/Production | Rollup  | Rollup     | Rollup  | Sales/Production | Rollup  | Rollup     | Rollup  | Sales/Production | Rollup  | Rollup     | Rollup  | Sales/Production |          | Shipped      |      |       |                |
| Rollup | T6T           | OEM            | FEDS     | 67C          | 5   | BS5        | 0000-00-00  | 105         | 250  | 2019-12-23     | 2019-12-22 | Rollup | Green | Rollup     | Green | Sales  | Title Transfer | Yellow     | Title Transfer | Sales  | Shipped | Rollup     | Shipped | Sales/Production | Shipped | Rollup     | Shipped | Sales/Production | Shipped | Rollup     | Shipped | Sales/Production | Shipped | Rollup     | Shipped | Sales/Production | Shipped | Rollup     | Shipped | Sales/Production | Shipped | Rollup     | Shipped | Sales/Production |          | Shipped      |      |       | x              |
```

FYI, I have 8 Days in total, each Day is a combination of 4 columns with the exact same order: Sales, Production, Day, Status. The range is from column N to column BS (or AS in an actual Excel workbook).

As seen from the table:

1) the 1st row did exactly what I wanted. It did evaluate correctly the "Title Transfer" in column Sales/column R (of Day 2) to be the last Sales column that has "Title Transfer" and return an "x" in column BX (or column AX in my excel file).

2) the 2nd row, the codes returned both correct and wrong results. 
I had put "Title Transfer" in a Sales column first, which the Macro then returned an "x" in column BX. That's correct.

However, when I put "Shipped" in column BU after having put "Title Transfer" first in column BX, the "x" was replaced by the Shipped codes I posted above. It did return "Rollup" for all empty Sales and Production cells when I put "Shipped" in column BU (47th column or column AU in my excel file). But the "x" to indicate Title Transfer was gone.

So here comes the problem I've been struggling with for the past week. Can you please advise how I can fix this problem?
3) the 3rd row is what I wanted my codes did if both "Shipped" in column BU and "x" in column BX (apparently it won't work)

To be short, my codes should have done the following:

1) If "Shipped" in column BU (AU in an actual Excel file) and no "x" in column BX (AX in an actual Excel file), then return "Rollup" for all empty Sales and Production cells

2) If "Title Transfer" in the last Sales column and no "Shipped" in column BU (AU in an actual Excel file), return "x" in column BX (AX in an actual Excel file)

3) If "Title Transfer" in the last Sales column (has to happen first) and "Shipped" in column BU (happens later) (AU in an actual Excel file), return "x" in column BX and "Shipped" in all empty Sales and Production cells

Can you please help how to get it to work that way? Thanks a lot and please let me know if you need more info.

Ps: This is what MasterChange has:

```
Public Sub MasterChange(SPD As Range)
    Dim rSales As Range
    Dim rProduction As Range
    Dim rDay As Range

    Set rSales = SPD.Cells(1, 1)
    Set rProduction = SPD.Cells(1, 2)
    Set rDay = SPD.Cells(1, 3)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If rSales = "Rollup" And rProduction = "Rollup" Then
        rDay = "Rollup"
    ElseIf rSales = "Rollup" And rProduction = "Green" Then
        rDay = "Green"
    ElseIf rSales = "Rollup" And rProduction = "Yellow" Then
        rDay = "Yellow"
'I have approximately 40 Ifs statements like those but above are just a few for demonstration
    End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: What does MasterChange() sub do ?

Comment: My guess is that when the empty Sales and Production cells are set to "Rollup" then "Title Transfer" is no longer the last Sales column (MaxCol) and the else condition Cells(Target.Row, 50).Value = "" removes the X.

Comment: @CDP1802 Hi, the MasterChange() has If/ElseIf statements to return values on Day cells. Also, per your 2nd comment, do you have a suggestion to fix the problem? Thanks  a lot for your help

Comment: I don't yet fully understand your code but maybe you need a flag called something like "Rolledup" that gets set when the empty cells are filled and use it later as a condition for removing x e.g. If RolledUp = False then  Cells(Target.Row, 50).Value = ""